# Take the mean of the top 10 entries in a column by partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, error-messaging

So I have a table with a unique key for every spatial area, and another unique key for every time that was measured, as well as the variable in Question. I created a 'MeasID' which concatenates these together (AreaKey_MeasureKey), and I want to make a new view that has that MeasID and takes the top 10 values for each unique MeasID. I am pretty sure I want to do this with a partition.

The variables I am drawing from to make the new view look like

| AreaKey | MeasureKey | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -------- | -------- | 2.34 |
| 1 | 1 | 4.56 |
| 1 | 2 | 7.23 |

I am not sure what the code for the view should be. I have found a lot of answers that talk about selecting the top fraction of a partition or selecting the top nth of a column but seemingly never combing these together.

I have tried things like the following

```sql
SELECT MeasID
    ,AVG(Variable) AS Variable_Avg
FROM (
    SELECT MeasID
        ,Variable
        ,ntile(10) OVER (
            PARTITION BY MeasID ORDER BY Variable
            ) AS nt
    FROM Table
    ) AS T
WHERE nt <= 1
GROUP BY MeasID
ORDER BY MeasID
```

However I believe this splits the partition into to and takes the top 1. I want to select the top 10, whether it is the size of 15 or 1150.

I want the result to look like

| MeasID | Variable_top10avg |
| --- | --- |
| 1_1 | (mean of top 10) |
| 1_2 | (mean of top 10) |

Could I please have some help?

Comment: Sample data for your original table would help your question.

Comment: Instead of `ntile(10) ... as nt ... WHERE nt <= 1`, try `ROW_NUMBER() ... as rn ... WHERE rn <= 10`. Also, if you want to select the top 10 *largest* values of Variable, I expect you need `ORDER BY Variable DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH 
        T AS (
            SELECT
            ROWNUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY MeasID 
                ORDER BY Variable DESC
            ) AS rn,
            MeasID
            Variable
            FROM Table
        )

    SELECT MeasID,
        AVG(Variable)
    FROM T
    WHERE rn <= 10 
    GROUP BY MeasID
    ORDER BY MeasID ASC;
```